# addEventListener and classList.add

Tags: javascript, oop, addeventlistener

Im working on a project where I need to export a JS class to be able to add a css class on click. However my code isn't working and I cannot for the life of me see what the problem is.

Any kind soul out there to help me out? m

```
import BaseFeature from '../../foundation/base/base';

const dropdown = document.querySelectorAll(dropdown)

export default class Dropdown extends BaseFeature {
    constructor(element) {
        super(element);
        this.el = element;
        this.initDomCache(); 

        dropdown.addEventListener('click', (el) => {
            el.target.classList.add('dropdown--open');
            console.log(el.target);
          });  
    }

}
```

```
<p>Click me to add class</p>
<div class="dropdown">
    <ul>
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>Ipsum</li>
    <li>Et</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: FIX: I have of course imported the js class in the html markup with data-behavior

Comment: can you create some demo so that one can see the problem and debug?

Comment: @Pritesh  Hey, the only message i'm receiving in the console is that 
Basically that addeventlistener is not a function

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): dropdown.addEventListener is not a function
new Dropdown
./src/feature/dropdown/dropdown.js:28:11
  25 |   this.dom.ul.parentNode
  26 |  );  */
  27 | 
> 28 |  dropdown.addEventListener('click', (el) => {
     |          ^  29 |   el.target.classList.add('dropdown--open');
  30 |   console.log(el.target);
  31 |    });

Comment: Ok, but can you please add it on codesandbox or jsfiddle or any such env so that I can have a look at it?

Comment: @Pritesh https://jsfiddle.net/babysnakes11/39L1ch7t/
 I can see now that I am missing something with the element that should be clicked. But I don't understand how or where to add it. 
Thank you som much for your help. You are awesome

Comment: Did you found the problem, because I see many errors in jsfiddle code especially in HTML and js code :)

Comment: I know the error but dont know how to fix them :(

Comment: @Pritesh I toke the html markup from my project so i missed a few div openings and closings. I have fixed them now :)

Comment: Try and have error free fiddle and see what you are querying is already there in HTML because your fiddle is not organized currently :)